# How do I convert multiple .pdf files to .ai files all at once?

Tags: pdf, adobe, batch-processing, adobe-illustrator

As a part of my job, my boss wants me to convert thousands of .pdfs into .ai format in Illustrator CS6 without having to open each individual file (among the thousands) and save each pdf as a .ai. I need to convert these files by the thousands with a few simple steps.

Using Illustrator CS6, I have tried to do this by using the batch option by applying the same action to multiple files, (2). I have chosen two folders for input and output. A source from which I get the pdfs and a destination for the converted .pdfs in .ai format are placed.

While the conversions are successful, the multiple files, in this case 2, opened up individually in Illustrator, I had to save them rudimentarily.

This is not what I need. I need to be able to automatically convert thousands of pdfs into .ai's, without having to open and save each and every one of them.

How do I do this?

Comment: For windows: http://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/ For Mac: http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/os-x/3-easy-ways-to-batch-rename-files-on-the-mac/ For Linux: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/renaming-multiple-files-at-a-shell-prompt.html

Comment: You might find a method in an Illustrator forum.  If you want to script the Illustrator GUI then `AutoIt` may help.  Alternately, a batch file can be helpful if you find a command line converter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this script as starting point. It works for singlepage .pdf files right away. For multipage files you will have to tweak it a bit more

```
(function(thisObj){

main();
function main(){
           var pdffiles = File.openDialog ('select one or more pdf files', '*.pdf', true);
        if(pdffiles  === null){
                return;
            }

        for(var f = 0; f < pdffiles.length;f++){
                var pdf = pdffiles[f];
//~                 alert(pdf);
                var doc = app.open (pdf);

            var namepattern = pdf.path + "/" + pdf.name + ".converted.ai";
             var newai  = null;
                if(!(File(namepattern).exists)){
                newai = new File(namepattern);
                }else{
                newai = File(namepattern);
                    }
                doc.saveAs(newai);
              doc.close (SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
          }
    }
})(this);
```

Comment: It works for me. I do not know how to use the code. here are the instructions from website: 
1. save above code as "pdf2ai.jsx"; 2. open Adobe Illustrator; 3. go to "File" -> "Script" -> "Other Script..." -> Choose the file pdf2ai.jsx -> Choose the PDF files (support multiple pdf files at once)